# TRIANGLE_FAN circle not drawn after draw squares with textures

Tags: android, opengl-es

*UPDATE: Summary:
I can draw a circle using TRIANGLE_FAN and, separately, I also can draw two squares with bitmaps as textures. But the problem is when I draw the textures and then the circles. Circles aren't drawn.*

I'm drawing two texturized squares (4 vertex each). Then I draw a circle using GL_TRIANGLE_FAN but it isn't being drawn correctly (see images).

When I draw the circles without the squares, it is drawn correctly.

Any ideas where could be the problem?

Please, ask for more information. Thanks

Adding some code that I think is important:

```
public void onSurfaceCreated(GL10 gl, EGLConfig config) {
    gl.glClearColor(0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f);
    gl.glShadeModel(GL10.GL_SMOOTH);
    gl.glFrontFace(GL10.GL_CCW);
    gl.glEnable(GL10.GL_CULL_FACE);
    gl.glEnable(GL10.GL_BLEND);
    gl.glCullFace(GL10.GL_BACK);
    gl.glBlendFunc(GL10.GL_SRC_ALPHA, GL10.GL_ONE_MINUS_SRC_ALPHA);
    gl.glEnableClientState(GL10.GL_VERTEX_ARRAY);
    gl.glEnable(GL10.GL_TEXTURE_2D);
}
public void onSurfaceChanged(GL10 gl, int w, int h) {
    gl.glViewport(0, 0, width, height);
    gl.glMatrixMode(GL10.GL_PROJECTION);
    gl.glOrthof(0, w, -0, h, -1, 1);
    gl.glMatrixMode(GL10.GL_MODELVIEW);
    gl.glLoadIdentity();
}

public void onDrawFrame(GL10 gl) {
    gl.glClear(GL10.GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);
    gl.glColor4f(1.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f);
    circle.draw(gl);
    needle.draw(gl);
    synchronized (tokens) {
        for (Token d : tokens) {
            d.draw(gl);
        }
    }
}
```

Update:
Some screenshots.
Without drawing circle and needle objects:
[image: Without bitmaps]

Drawing circle and needle:
[image: With bitmaps]
(Look at those red lines where should be a circle)

The only change in the code between those images is commenting the lines

```
circle.draw(gl);
needle.draw(gl);
```

Token:

```
public void draw(GL10 gl) {
    gl.glVertexPointer(3, GL10.GL_FLOAT, 0, vertexBuffer);

    gl.glPushMatrix();
    gl.glTranslatef(x, y, 0f);
    gl.glScalef(radius, radius, 0f);
    gl.glColor4f(1.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f);
    gl.glDrawArrays(GL10.GL_TRIANGLE_FAN, 0, nVertices+2);
    gl.glPopMatrix();
}
```

Circle and Needle:

```
    public void draw(GL10 gl) {
    gl.glVertexPointer(3, GL10.GL_FLOAT, 0, vertexBuffer);

    if (shouldLoadTexture) {
        loadGLTexture(gl);
        shouldLoadTexture = false;
    }


    gl.glTexCoordPointer(2, GL10.GL_FLOAT, 0, textureBuffer);
    gl.glBindTexture(GL10.GL_TEXTURE_2D, textureId);

    gl.glPushMatrix();
    gl.glTranslatef(x, y, 0f);
    gl.glRotatef((float) angle, 0f, 0f, 1f);
    angle += rotAngle;
    if(angle+rotAngle > 360.0)
        angle -= 360.0;
    gl.glScalef(width, height, 0f);
    gl.glDrawElements(GL10.GL_TRIANGLES, indices.length,
            GL10.GL_UNSIGNED_SHORT, indexBuffer);
    gl.glPopMatrix();

}

private void loadGLTexture(GL10 gl) {

    int[] textures = new int[1];
    gl.glGenTextures(1, textures, 0);
    textureId = textures[0];

    gl.glBindTexture(GL10.GL_TEXTURE_2D, textureId);

    gl.glTexParameterf(GL10.GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL10.GL_TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER,
            GL10.GL_LINEAR);
    gl.glTexParameterf(GL10.GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL10.GL_TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER,
            GL10.GL_LINEAR);


    gl.glTexParameterf(GL10.GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL10.GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_S,
            GL10.GL_CLAMP_TO_EDGE);
    gl.glTexParameterf(GL10.GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL10.GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_T,
            GL10.GL_REPEAT);

    GLUtils.texImage2D(GL10.GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, bitmap, 0);
}
```

Update:

Following what Arne says in the first answer, I changed:

```
public void draw(GL10 gl) {
            //New line
            gl.glEnableClientState(GL10.GL_TEXTURE_COORD_ARRAY);
    gl.glVertexPointer(3, GL10.GL_FLOAT, 0, vertexBuffer);

    if (shouldLoadTexture) {
        loadGLTexture(gl);
        shouldLoadTexture = false;
    }


    gl.glTexCoordPointer(2, GL10.GL_FLOAT, 0, textureBuffer);
    gl.glBindTexture(GL10.GL_TEXTURE_2D, textureId);

    gl.glPushMatrix();
    gl.glTranslatef(x, y, 0f);
    gl.glRotatef((float) angle, 0f, 0f, 1f);
    angle += rotAngle;
    if(angle+rotAngle > 360.0)
        angle -= 360.0;
    gl.glScalef(width, height, 0f);
    gl.glDrawElements(GL10.GL_TRIANGLES, indices.length,
            GL10.GL_UNSIGNED_SHORT, indexBuffer);
    gl.glPopMatrix();
            //New line
            gl.glDisableClientState(GL10.GL_TEXTURE_COORD_ARRAY);
}
```

Now I get no circle at all. Neither red line as in the second image.

Update:

When I don't load the texture of circle and needle (just commenting the call to loadTexture() ), I get this:

[image: Commenting loadTexture()]

So the problem should be with the textures.

Comment: Well don't ask us for more information, put more information yourself because your question is very vague without some code. It's like asking a person to diagnose something without a context.

Comment: You're right. I added more info. Thanks

Comment: Could you add the draw code for circle, needle and Token, respectivly?

Comment: you are doing way to many state changes for a mobile device, its going to serisouly lower your frame rate. OpenGL is a state machine so once its enabled it stays enabled until disabled

Comment: @Chris What lines do you think could be improved? I think enabling in onSurfaceCreated is a good moment.

Comment: well a lot of your code looks like it should be drawing in 3D but it seems you are only using 2D? Try to get ride of gl rotate/translate and do you need the matrix operations?

Comment: @Chris I use glRotate to move the needle like a clock. I use scale and translate to position the bitmaps on the screen.
What things can I remove for draw in only 2D?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You enable texturing (by calling `glEnable(GL_TEXTURE_2D)`) at the beginning, but you don't provide your circles (tokens) any texture coordinates. As I suppose these shouldn't be textured, you should only enable texturing for the objects that are really textured and disable texturing again after drawing them, the same way you enable and disable the texCoord array in your updated code.

Answer (score 1):

Try to disable GL_TEXTURE_COORD_ARRAY before drawing the circles with

```
gl.glDisableClientState(GL10.GL_TEXTURE_COORD_ARRAY);
```

Comment: I'm now enabling GL_TEXTURE_COORD_ARRAY at the beginning of draw method of circle and needle and disabling at the end.

Now, no "lines" are drawn but no circles neither